# react-navigation more page header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

tab and stack，When used, multiple header appears after the jump to the next page style, I react - navigation configuration has a problem?Have a better solution?
this is app entrance :

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button } from 'antd-mobile';
import C from './C';
import D from './D';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onClick={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('cc')}>A页面</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onClick={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('dd')}>B页面</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const tab = TabNavigator({
  c: {
    screen: App, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'A',
    }
  },
  d: {
    screen: B, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'B'
    }
  },
});
tab.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'A和B',
};
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: tab },
  cc: { screen: C },
  dd: {screen: D},
});

export default SimpleApp;
```

---

this is C page code :

C.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List,Button } from 'antd-mobile';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class C extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({  
        title: 'C页面',  
    }); 
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button>C页面</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default C;
```

---

this is D page code:

D.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List,Button } from 'antd-mobile';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import E from './E';

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class D extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({  
        title: 'D页面', 
    });
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onClick={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ee')}>D页面</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Simple = StackNavigator({  
    dd: { screen: D },
    ee: { screen: E },  
  });
export default Simple;
```

---

this is E page code :

E.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List,Button } from 'antd-mobile';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class E extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({  
        title: 'E页面',  
    });
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button>E页面</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default E;
```

[image]
[image]
**TabNavigator and mord StackNavigator ，why?
A->C->D error?
My configuration errors occur in where？？？**

Answer (score 1):

There is headerMode option which you can add to your navigatorsOptions,

try headerMode:'none' in your child navigators

[check doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)